# Footer comes up if in a separate column in css

Tags: html, css

This is how it is:

```css
.technology {
  width: 100%;
}

.technology-left {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 8000px;
  margin-bottom: -8000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.technology-right {
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="technology">
  <div class="technology-left">
    VERY LONG ACCORDION MENU
  </div>

  <div class="technology-right">
    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if there is no content or very less content in class content or if any main link in my accordion has quite a number of sub-links and when it opens, then footer comes up showing white space below footer.

How can I solve this by keeping the footer at the base, not fixed?

Also one more small thing (not mentioned in the heading though), when I see in Safari that technology-left thing just keeps scrolling down, I assume it does not take -8000px or overflow?

Here is an illustration of the problem:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTEQm.jpg)

Comment: `padding-bottom: 8000px;
  margin-bottom: -8000px;` why ?

Comment: because i need a full height and has another background color and works fine in chrome, firefox and ie, but i checked on ipad in safari and it doesnt work.

Comment: @MustafaAliasgar why don't you just change the background color then? the margin and padding values  are huge.. bound to throw the appearance off

Comment: I am not sure it is entirely clear what the problem is. Is it demonstrated by the snippet, or does this need a screenshot?

Comment: `because i need a full height` : there is a property called height :) and many values to make *full height*. What you did is a hack and not a correct way to achieve what you need

Comment: @RachelGallen Ma'am it wont look beautiful, it looks tidy and separated, i have also applied inset box shadow and all, for a good view :(

Comment: You can make use of min-height:90vh or something remove the insanely huge negative padding and margin?

Comment: @halfer unfortunately i cant see demonstration in the snippet :(

Comment: @MustafaAliasgar please post more code (representative of the problem, your code given is very minimal) or make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Mustafa: okay, if the `Run code snippet` button does not show the problem you are referring to, perhaps it would be a good idea for you to include a screenshot in the question. Without it, the question might close (it could be just me that does not follow it, so it is up to you).

Comment: @Highdef yes sir that worked very well, thank you, but my footer problem still remains

Comment: @MustafaAliasgar What footer problem now?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is to go with flex. And in order to make footer at the bottom simply use `margin-top:auto`.

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.technology {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.technology-left {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.technology-right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="technology">
  <div class="technology-left">
    VERY LONG ACCORDION MENU
  </div>

  <div class="technology-right">
    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the `margin-top:auto;` trick. It's logic, but I never thought about using it this way. +1.

Answer (score 1):

For your layout I'd use `flexbox` *:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.technology {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.technology>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.technology-left {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}

.technology>div, .technology-right>div {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.technology .technology-right {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer {
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="technology">
  <div class="technology-left">
    VERY LONG ACCORDION MENU
  </div>

  <div class="technology-right">
    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

* Don't forget to [prefix](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: we used different ways by the way to make footer at the bottom ;) so +1 for yours too

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to achieve full height layout where footer always stays at the bottom and left right portion should be scrollable when overflow. I don't feel any need for that long margin and padding, you can have your layout without that. here i have updated your code

```css
.technology {
  width: 100%;
}

.technology-left {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  float:left;
  background: #eee;
}

.technology-right {
  width: 85%;
  float:left;
  height:100vh;
}
.footer{
  height:50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.content {
  height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="technology">
  <div class="technology-left">
    VERY LONG ACCORDION MENU
  </div>

  <div class="technology-right">
    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this way your footer always stays at the bottom and technology-left is scrollable when overflown.